# Assign constants to an object

Tags: java, inheritance, constants

I have an abstract class, Animal, which has several subclasses such as Dog, Cat and Rabbit.

Each of these subclasses uses the constructor of the Animal class, but every object from a subclass should also need so constants. A Dog object shoould always have animalNumber = 1, and every Dog object should have an attribute maximumNumberOfAnimals = 5. But every Cat object should always have animalNumber = 2, and every Cat object should have an attribute maximumNumberOfAnimals = 10.

How can i code this?

This is what i have so far:

This is the superclass:

```
public abstract class Animal {
private int weight;
private int height;

public Animal (int weight, int height) {
setWeight(weight);
setHeight(height);
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
public void setWeight(int weight) {
     this.weight = weight;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}
}
```

This is a subclass

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

public static final int ANIMALNUMBER= 1;
public static final int MAXIMUMNUMBERALLOWED= 5;

//the constructor
public Dog (int weight, int height, int animalNumber, int maximumNumberAllowed) {
    super(weight, height)
    Dog.animalNumber = ANIMALNUMBER;
    Dog.maximumNumberAllowed = MAXIMUMNUMBERALLOWED;
}
}
```

This is another subclass

```
public class Cat extends Animal {

public static final int ANIMALNUMBER= 2;
public static final int MAXIMUMNUMBERALLOWED= 10;

//the constructor
public Cat (int weight, int height, int animalNumber, int maximumNumberAllowed) {
    super(weight, height)
    Cat.animalNumber = ANIMALNUMBER;
    Cat.maximumNumberAllowed = MAXIMUMNUMBERALLOWED;
}
}
```

what i want in the end is this:

If I call the constructor to make a new 'Dog' using Dog Lassie = new Dog(40, 60, 1, 5). But i should not be allowed to do this: Dog Lassie = new Dog(40, 60, 2, 10)So for every Dog, the ANIMALNUMBER should be 1, for every Cat, the ANIMALNUMBER should be 2. It's an instance variable but it should be the same for every instance of the class.

This not only says: The final field Dog.ANIMALNUMBERcannot be assigned
But i also think it will not work. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn´t make sense to make them `final` and `static` whilst reassigning them in the constructor. You´re probably mixing up some things. You should probably add what you´re trying to do with these variables.

Comment: Where did the `Villa` come from? It's not in any of the code you have given. That error doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Sorry, that was some other class in which i get the same error. Indeed, this doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Comment: Well, you do have some mixup. You are assigning to `Cat.animalNumber`. Using the class name implies the variable is a `static` variable, but you don't have any such field, static or otherwise, in your class. And if it's supposed to be static, well, you already declared constants in the class, why create and assign others, and do so in the constructor? Try to give the exact instructions you got, and study static vs. instance fields.

Comment: @Waterfles could you explain what `ANIMALNUMBER` is supposed to be doing? should it be something like an identificationnumber for each individual `Dog` (instance) or an identificationnumber for a `Dog` itself (static)

Comment: I have the idea that i have to mention the attributes in the constructor as i want them to be attributes of the objects. But i want the values to be always the same.
So if I call the constructor to make a new 'Dog' using Dog Lassie = new Dog(40, 60, 1, 5).
But i should not be allowed to do this: Dog Lassie = new Dog(40, 60, 2, 10)So for every Dog, the ANIMALNUMBER should be 1, for every Cat, the ANIMALNUMBER should be 2. It's an instance variable but it should be the same for every instance of the class.

Comment: and what is the `MAXIMUMNUMBERALLOWED` variable there for? It´s still unclear for me what your purpose for these values is. They should be unique yeah, though making me think they shouldn´t be static. But what will they be there for in the end? how do you want to make use of them?

Comment: @Waterfles by the way, you can also edit your previous comment instead of just copieing it ;) If that´s necessary information you should also include it in the question

Comment: The MAXIMUMNUMBERALLOWED variable will be used to limit an owner of having more than 5 dogs.

Comment: If i would not add the MAXIMUMNUMBERALLOWED and ANIMALNUMBER in the constructor. But only define them in the subclass as 'public static final' as I did, can I still call the variable from a Dog object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So for every Dog, the ANIMALNUMBER should be 1, for every Cat, the ANIMALNUMBER should be 2.

You overcomplicated things. The easiest solution is this to remove the Constructor parameter and leave the `ANIMALNUMBER` as is.

**But**

Defining an ID for the subclass implies that you later plan to do some special action bases on the `ANIMALNUMBER` of an animal.

This is not what we want when we do OOP`.

Wat ever you later want do do based on `ANIMALNUMBER` should be done in a method in the concrete "Animal" implementation (like `Dog`) overriding an abstract method in class `Animal`

```
 public abstract class Animal {
  // common fields
   public Animal (int weight, int height) {
    // initialize
   }

   public abstract sting giveSound();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   @Override
   public  sting giveSound(){
     return "Wooff";
}


public class Cat extends Animal {
   @Override
   public  sting giveSound(){
     return "Meaw";
}

public class Rabbit extends Animal {
   @Override
   public  sting giveSound(){
     return "";
}
```

---

**[edit]**

> I will place these animals in a grid at some point. And I would like to count the number of Dogs, Cats and Rabbits I have.

I have to admit that this is some kind of Corner case...

> Can i count them based on their class?

Yes, by using a `Map`:

```
 public abstract class Animal {
   public addToCount(Map<String,Integer> counters){
     // gets the class name of the child that has been called *new* on...
     String myClassName =  getClass().getName(); 
     Integer oldCount = conters.getOrDefault(myClassName, Integer.ZERO);
     conters.put(myClassName,oldCount.add(Integer.ONE));
   }
}
```

Comment: I will place these animals in a grid at some point. And I would like to count the number of Dogs, Cats and Rabbits I have. Can i count them based on their class?

Comment: @Waterfles *"Can i count them based on their class?"* see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can add these two attributes to `Animal` and initialize them from the children classes:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private int weight;
    private int height;
    private final int number;
    private final int maximumAllowed;

    public Animal(int weight, int height, int number, int maximumAllowed) {
        setWeight(weight);
        setHeight(height);
        this.number = number;
        this.maximumAllowed = maximumAllowed;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public final int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public final int getMaximumAllowed() {
        return maximumAllowed;
    }
}

public final class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(int weight, int height) {
        super(weight, height, 1, 5);
    }
}

public final class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat(int weight, int height) {
        super(weight, height, 2, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want set values of constants in constructor, you should make them non-static.
But now you have the global constants and it does not make sense to pass animalNumber and maximumNumberAllowed to constructor. Your constants will always have the same values you set like this:

```
public static final int MAXIMUMNUMBERALLOWED = 10;
```

And the constants of Dog class are not relevant to constants of Cat class!